# calling a function whenever the slider is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one slider in my code. when I click on it, it should call a function myFunction() in my code which alerts a message clicked.

Here is my code which is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
      $("#slider-1").slider({
           range: true,
           min: 0,
           max: 500,
           values: [0, 0],
           slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#priceA").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
           },
           stop: function () {
                getValues();
           }
      });
      $('.myClass').click(function(){
        myFunction();
      });
      function myFunction(){
        alert("Called");
      }
   });           
</script>
</head>
<p>
    <label for="priceA">Price rangeA:</label>
    <input type="text" id="priceA" style="border:0; color:#067ab4; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-1" class="myClass"></div><br><br>
</html>
```

Comment: The jquery ui is probably preventing event bubbling. What do you mean by "it isn't working"? Is there being an error thrown? Or just nothing happening.

Comment: @Stephen. Nothing happening for me. I want to alert the message but I am unable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use the events already provided by the slider? There's no click event exposed, but surely the change or stop events will work?

http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/d23X2/

```
$("#slider-1").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [0, 0],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#priceA").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        myFunction();
    }
});

function myFunction() {
    alert("Called");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I deleted all my wrong answers. The following should work.

It appears that jquery-ui is capturing and swallowing the `click` event. That's why you can't handle it, it's not bubbling! (as far as I can tell). What you want to do is bind to the slider's `start` event instead. This will be like hooking into the click event.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/U3qx5/12/

Comment: The op never referenced `this`. In fact, scope shouldn't even be a problem here.

Comment: Then maybe all he has to do is place the function definition above the handler definition?

Comment: That shouldn't be needed either - JS hoists function declarations.

Comment: @Thedeeno. its not working for me. can you please do it in jsfiddle and comment the link.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to setup the function outside of your initial function. It will look like this:

```
$(function () {

         $("#slider-1").slider({
             range: true,
             min: 0,
             max: 500,
             values: [0, 0],
             slide: function (event, ui) {
                 $("#priceA").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
             },
             stop: function () {
                 getValues();
             }
         });


     });

$("#slider-1").click(function(){
alert('Called');
});
```

Comment: You're suggesting that the op attaches events to something that may not even be finished loading here.

Comment: It works. Also he can put a document.ready function around it to secure its load.

Comment: @Drew. Can you do it in jsfiddle and comment the link please.

Comment: I tried it in chrome. It works when you click on the little square attached on the div.

Comment: You also may want to consider a mouseup event that triggers once the 'sliding' has completed.

Comment: @ Drew.Its working after including my jquery code inside document.ready function. Thanks